# Jquery and closure or function reference not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think it has something to do with a function running in a difference scope from where the jquery library is not accessable (shown being called as the last parameter on the second line below)

```
var funcExpandHeight = container.animate({
    height: '300px'
}, 300, function () {});
foo.animate({
    height: 'show'
}, 300, funcExpandHeight);
```

Line one works, then crashes on `'f.easing[i.animatedProperties[this.prop]] is not a function'`

Munging the lines up together as show below, and the operation completes successfully.

```
    foo.animate({
     height: 'show'
 }, 300, function () {
     container.animate({
         height: container[0].scrollHeight + 'px'
     }, 300, function () {})
 });
```

Comment: the `var funcExpandHeight = container.animat(..)` does not create a function... it creates a jquery object (*and immediately executes the animation*)).. and that is not a valid parameter for the callback of the next `animate`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Third argument of `.animate()` is callback function, but in your first code you're just passing a variable.

```
var funcExpandHeight = function() {
   container.animate({height: '300px'}, 300, function(){});
}
foo.animate({height: 'show'}, 300, funcExpandHeight);
```

---

#### NOTE

config of **[`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)** is like following:

```
.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )
```

Where `[]` means optional.

In your code, you don't give the `easing` so, the third argument will treat as complete callback function.

#### For more detail see above link.